# vim-airline doesn't display before launching Tagbar

Tags: vim, vim-airline

I installed airline using vundle.

After that, the vim console don't have any change on the bottom.

But when I launch Tagbar, it will display the status line on the bottom.

How to enable status line on the botton when vim launches ?

Comment: well, already fix that when i do "set laststatus=2".

Comment: Maybe answer this one yourself @chuck, just so nobody misses it.